# Python user input replay

Tags: python, input, raw-input, replay

How can I get the last raw_input? My py asks questions(raw_input) and if user types wrong asks the same again and user needs to type all over again, so how can I get last input to make de user just edit it??(like a shell pressing key-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`readline` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html). Here's an [example from effbot.org](http://effbot.org/librarybook/readline.htm):

```
# File: readline-example-2.py

class Completer:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.words = words
        self.prefix = None
    def complete(self, prefix, index):
        if prefix != self.prefix:
            # we have a new prefix!
            # find all words that start with this prefix
            self.matching_words = [
                w for w in self.words if w.startswith(prefix)
                ]
            self.prefix = prefix
        try:
            return self.matching_words[index]
        except IndexError:
            return None

import readline

# a set of more or less interesting words
words = "perl", "pyjamas", "python", "pythagoras"

completer = Completer(words)

readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(completer.complete)

# try it out!
while 1:
    print repr(raw_input(">>> "))
```

Comment: You don't actually need a completer if you just want command history. Importing `readline` is enough to initialize the history feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) module.

```
import readline

# Everything magically works now!
```

There are more sophisticated features available if you want tab completion and other goodies.